# ClangFormat: Option to break before bracket on multi-line ifs?

Tags: clang-format

Does a clang-format option exists which inserts a line break before brackets only in conditionals that span multiple lines? For example:

```cpp
if (condition_a && condition_b) { /* Do not break before bracket here */
    ...
} else if(condition_c && condition_d &&
          condition_e && condition_f) /* Condition spans multiple lines, break before bracket */
{

}
```

Thank you.